# Push notifications iOS - prompt app to check resource and provide local notification if appropriate

Tags: ios, swift, rss, apple-push-notifications

I am looking into creating an iOS app in Swift along with a remote service that notifies users when an update to an RSS feed occurs only when the update meets certain criteria. A user story would be as follows:

1. User installs app and decides to be updated when a feed update includes certain words (for example in the title). This relates to a specific 3rd party feed, the address of which is stored in the app.
2. When the 3rd party RSS feed is updated, if the title matches the condition previously selected by the user, a notification is made to the user.

I'm trying to work out whether I need a server with a script to monitor the feed and to send updates to the user, however it will send all updates, the phone would then need to check the update and only notify the user if it matched their conditions.

Or, is it better to have the app run periodic background checks against the feed so it can check itself if the update warrants a local notification? This would need to be able to run when the app is completely closed.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An app can only decide to notify the user about an incoming notification if the app is currently in use by the user.  If closed or in the background, the notification is going to come through to the device and register.  If you need to filter which notifications get pushed, you need a backend server process to do the filtering and push out only the applicable notices.

We did a system where the user was able to set search criteria for animals they would be interested in adopting.  That was stored in the database.  A service on the database server ran every 30 minutes and queried the various search criteria for each person and pushed out a notification to that user if a new pet was found matching their criteria.  Once a notification had been sent for that pet for that user, a flag was set that would prevent the user getting another notification about the same pet 30 minutes later... there are a lot of use cases to consider!!

Comment: Ah ok so in that model, when a user registers, the app would need to collect a user ID along with their notification preferences, the backend would then only send notifications associated with a particular user to their device?

Comment: Correct.  And, in our system, if a user logged in from both an Android and an iOS device, each app would need to register their unique id's.  Since the notifications are tied to both the login id and the device ids, separate notifications would get sent out for each platform.